# When user clicks on radio button, hide all other options and make label zoom in and animate?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an emoji based rating system,

firstly i was wondering how can i make the label / emoji icon zoom in a little on a hover so it becomes bigger than the others?

Secondly, when you click on one of the radio buttons, can i hide all unclicked radio buttons and then animate the clicked label to stay zoomed in?

```
 <div class ="rating text-center  left-20" style="display: flex;">
               <div class="checkboxgroup">
                <input id="box1-fac-radio" type="radio" name="rad" value="1" style="visibility:hidden">
                <label for="box1-fac-radio"><i class ="twf twf-pensive twf-4x"></i></label>
                        </div>
                         <div class="checkboxgroup">
             <input id="box1-fac-radio1" type="radio" name="rad" value="2" style="visibility:hidden">
             <label for="box1-fac-radio1"><i class ="twf twf-neutral-face twf-4x"></i></label>
                      </div>
                       <div class="checkboxgroup">
             <input id="box1-fac-radio2" type="radio" name="rad" value="3" style="visibility:hidden">
             <label for="box1-fac-radio2"><i class ="twf twf-satisfied twf-4x"></i></label>
                 </div>
                  <div class="checkboxgroup">
                <input id="box1-fac-radio3" type="radio" name="rad" value="4" style="visibility:hidden">
               <label for="box1-fac-radio3"><i class ="twf twf-grin twf-4x"></i></label>
                  </div>
                   <div class="checkboxgroup">

             <input id="box1-fac-radio4" type="radio" name="rad" value="5" style="visibility:hidden">
            <label for="box1-fac-radio4"><i class ="twf twf-heart-eyes twf-4x"></i></label>

          </div>
```

thanks

Comment: Share a snippet of your code.

Comment: Whoops, i pressed submit and forgot to add my code!

Comment: Better yet, add a snippit of relevant code so others can fiddle with your code as is and potentially give you a working answer that fits your criteria!